# Equivalent norm in homeomorphic spaces

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ be two norms on a *real vector* space $X$ such that the resulting spaces with induced topologies are homeomorphic, i.e., there exists a bicontinuous bijection $X\to X$.

Is it true that these two norms have to be necessarily equivalent? [I think the answer is positive as in the classical case of different norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$]

Comment: In the classical case, the answer is indeed positive: the induced topologies are the same for all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$; in other words the identity map is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\nrm}[1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}\newcommand{\norm}{\nrm\bullet}$
No. Pick a $\norm_1$-discontinuous linear isomorphism $T:X\to X$ and call $\nrm{x}_2:=\nrm{Tx}_1$

Since $T$ is discontinuous as a map of normed spaces $(X,\norm_1)\to(X,\norm_1)$, by definition $\nrm{x}_2\le C\nrm{x}_1$ cannot hold for all $x$ and a fixed constant $C$.

However, $T:(X,\norm_2)\to(X,\norm_1)$ is a bijective isometry.

Comment: @user228113 I think you're wrong. Take a look at my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

By definition, two metrics, $\rho$ and $\sigma$ on a metric space, $X$, is said to be equivalent if the identity mapping of $\langle X,\rho\rangle$ onto $\langle X, \sigma \rangle$ is homomorphism.

Now if two metrics are (different) norms, the inverse image of every open set is open in the other space, hence (by definition) the identity map is continuous (in both directions), hence it's homomorphism, Hence they are equivalent.

Comment: The homeomorphism is not required to be the identity. Actually it is not even required to be a linear map.